# Plot large raster in R

Tags: r, plot, raster

I've got a large (8GB) raster file that I'd like to plot in R. I try to do the below, but I run out of memory. I'd like some input and ideas on what to do please? Thanks, James.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

# ---- setting the colours ------------#
my.at <- c( 0,0.5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30,35,40,45,50, 100, 260)

colours<-c("paleturquoise","lightcyan", "brown","burlywood","bisque2","darkorange2","lightpink",
       "darkred","gold1","mediumorchid1","hotpink2", "darkblue","darkblue", "violetred4","violetred4")

    pdf("plot_1b.pdf", width=10, height=20)           
    par(bty='n')
    par(mar=c(0, 0,0,0))
    plot(raster("2015-06-23_001403_21674_63649.grd"), 
         xlim=c(-1200000, -650000), 
         ylim=c(-260000,550000), 
         maxpixels=445500000000, 
         breaks=my.at,
         col = colours,
         lab.breaks=my.at, 
         legend=FALSE, 
         axes=FALSE)
    dev.off()
```

Comment: 445,500,000,000 pixels is something like an image of nearly 700,000 pixels by 700,000 pixels. Your PDF is 10" x 20", so a resolution on the order of 70,000 pixels per inch. Printers are typically 300 to 1200 pixels per inch. You really can't show all these pixels. The `maxpixels` argument is designed to allow you to downsample in just this kind of situation. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We are trying to make a very detailed map of the UK showing air quality. It's not designed to actually be printed, but to be something that people can download and zoom right in to cities to see the detail that is available on streets/roads etc.

Comment: And you want to deliver this as a PDF? I really don't think that will work. Ever. Create map tiles at different zoom levels and make a web interface.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Thank you for your help @Spacedman . I'll look into that. Going off-topic now I realise, but could you point me in the right direction for a tutorial? Cheers.

Comment: gdal2tiles might be what you are looking for for this. Part of GDAL suite so you might already have it installed. Good luck! http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html